# Light ignoring a solid object to illuminate object hidden behind the solid object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, render-layers

I have a scene where it would be great if the following would be possible either through Cycles or Render Layers.

[image: problem]

I want to have a light source behind a solid object (no transparency or glass shader). Is it possible that this light source illuminates an object in FRONT of the solid object: Thereby it is important that the light is not influenced in any way. It should completely ignore the solid object.

Does anybody know a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the shadow option on the wall object.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for! Thanks! @lemon